# I would like to use dplyr::mutate than plyr::ddply function in pipeline processing

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, tibble

I would like to do the same what I have done here by mutate function not by ddplyr one. Is it possible to perform not vectorized operation here somehow?

```
test <- tibble::tibble(
  x = c(1,2,3),
  y = c(0.5,1,1.5)
)
d <- c(1.23, 0.99, 2.18)

test %>% mutate(., s = (function(x, y) {
  dn <- dnorm(x = d, mean = x, sd = y)
  s <- sum(dn)
  s
})(x,y))

test %>% plyr::ddply(., c("x","y"), .fun = function(row) {
  dn <- dnorm(x = d, mean = row$x, sd = row$y)
  s <- sum(dn)
  s
})
```

Comment: `test %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(...)` is the ticket to get a rowwise grouping for operations

Answer (score 0):

A popular method is using the `dplyr` function: `rowwise()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- tibble::tibble(
  x = c(1,2,3),
  y = c(0.5,1,1.5)
)
d <- c(1.23, 0.99, 2.18)

test %>% 
  rowwise() %>%                                # prior to mutate specify calculate rowwise
  mutate(., s = (function(x, y) {
    dn <- dnorm(x = d, mean = x, sd = y)
    s <- sum(dn)
    s})(x,y))
```

This yields the following result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     y     s
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   0.5 1.56 
2     2   1   0.929
3     3   1.5 0.470
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me the wrong answer. 
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     y     s
* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   0.5  1.19
2     2   1    1.19
3     3   1.5  1.19
Should be:
  x   y        V1
1 1 0.5 1.5647681
2 2 1.0 0.9286773
3 3 1.5 0.4699930

Comment: The numbers are the same, they are just rounded to two decimal values.

Comment: If you run code with ddply as result you have 1.5647681, 0.9286773, 1.5 0.4699930. This is what I have expected from code. It could be even rounded. :) Solution is map() function probably.

Comment: Running the code I have above yield the rounded result you desire. Are you not getting this same result? I don't understand how to help.

Comment: The number of decimal places shown in console printout depends on global options you may have set, as well as the object type that `print` is being called on. If there's a discrepancy in the number of places printed, check the actual values stored, not just what's printed out